# In a PivotChart filter, how do I select a just range in the column to display?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table, powerpivot

Help! I have created a pivot chart that shows 3 data series across iterations (time). All series are shown as 'running total in' base field: iterations.

The series are:

- Total Hours Planned
- Capacity in Hours
- Completed Work

They would like to see the series Total Hours Planned and Capacity in Hours through the end of the year, but Completed Work only through the current iteration. Not sure how to apply a filter only to one series and not to the others? This will be widely used so I am trying to keep it as simple and/or automated as possible. Ideally they'd like a trendline that starts at the current iteration to predict completed work through the end of the year... but I'd settle for filter. (updated to align with new titles)

[image]

Comment: TTL stands for what? Time to Live? Do you have a screenshot of what you currently have and what'd you like to see? I guess I don't understand why you can't exclude data from Sum of Complete Work up to today. Where are you pulling the data from and can you import it up to just today? I understand you want to project or display actual values for total story points and total capacity to the end of the year.

Comment: TTL = Total. Data is coming from TFS and to get total story points (total hours planned on screenshot - just added to original post) i pull in all iterations with data - filtering data source would effectively filter all series instead of just the one.

Comment: TFS is what? Please define acronyms before using them

Comment: TFS - Team Foundation Server, same as Microsoft Visual Studio, a tool for managing product backlogs. Apologies, some forums are specific to that integration and I forget to specify :)

Comment: So, you're saying you want the Blue to stop at 2016.05.31? This data is also coming from TFS and it gives you the Sum of Completed Work to the end of the year, even though the work for those future dates hasn't actually been completed? Can you show you receive the data in TFS? Either the CSV or XLSX file? Do you have a cloud sharing service like OneDrive, Dropbox, etc that you can use to link the source data?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm looking for! The data that comes in is a hierarchical list of stories and tasks (subset of stories). Stories have the Total Hours Planned (story points) and tasks have total hours completed

Comment: Hit enter too early ...list of stories and tasks (subset of stories). Users track Total Hours Planned (story points) at the story level and Total Hours Completed at the task level. Future dates for tasks just show 0 in completed. Exports from TFS as a XLSX file. I don't have cloud sharing.   Also would like to say thank you for all the clarifying questions, I have a lot to learn about posting/interacting on forums. I will look up tip guide, if you have a favorite please send along.

Comment: Here's what I found on asking questions here... http://superuser.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy way partially display column data. It'd be easier to set up a separate sheet that looks up the Data from the PivotTable, do some additional logic on it, then display a PivotChart from the processed data.

Here's what I did based on your screenshot. I copied the data and added two more columns called Show? and ShowCompletedWork. The formula for ShowCompletedWork is `=IF(E2="yes",B2,"")`

I think others have used the [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) function to do what you want, but seems like a lot of effort.

```
Date,CompletedWork,Total Hours Planned,Capacity In Hours,Show?,ShowCompletedWork
19-Apr-2016,1000,1200,2500,yes,1000
3-May-2016,5000,5000,5000,yes,5000
17-May-2016,7000,7500,7500,yes,7000
31-May-2016,8000,8500,10000,yes,8000
14-Jun-2016,8000,10000,12500,,
28-Jun-2016,8000,15000,15000,,
12-Jul-2016,8000,17500,17500,,
26-Jul-2016,8000,21000,20000,,
9-Aug-2016,8000,27000,22500,,
23-Aug-2016,8000,31000,25000,,
6-Sep-2016,8000,37000,27500,,
20-Sep-2016,8000,40500,30000,,
4-Oct-2016,8000,46000,32500,,
18-Oct-2016,8000,49000,35000,,
1-Nov-2016,8000,52000,37500,,
15-Nov-2016,8000,53000,40000,,
29-Nov-2016,8000,55000,42500,,
13-Dec-2016,8000,59000,45000,,
27-Dec-2016,8000,61000,47500,,
```

I created a PivotChart from that data:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FANTASTIC!!  This was the solution:
Created PivotTable to get sum of completed work
Created table to keep running total (formula bar)
Added to data model on iteration, swapped out the old line with new!
[Tables Created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMyVT.jpg)

It will require manual update biweekly, but small price to pay to even get the trendline they were looking for.  Thank you Sun!!